# Is there a better design in mongodb to make a package/wallet system?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to create a package/wallet system with different users.

I have 4 collections in mongodb:

**Business**

```
const businessSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: { type: String, unique: true },
  .
  .
  .
  packages: [{
    kind: String,
    price: Number,
    numberOfitems: Number
  }]

})
```

**User**

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userName: { type: String, unique: true },
  userType: {
    type: String,
    enum: ["USER", "BusinessOwner"],
    default: "USER"
  }
  .
  .
  .
  wallets:[{
    businessID: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Business'},
    numberOfItems: Number,
    kind: String
  }]

})
```

**Purchases**

```
const purchasesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userID: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  businessID: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Business'},
  purchasedPackage:{
    numberOfItems: Number,
    kind: String,
    price: Number
  }

})
```

**Redeemed Order**

```
const orderSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  userID: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
  businessID: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Business'},
  order:{
    numberOfItems: Number,
    kind: String
  }

})
```

The flow of business logic goes like this:

- A business owner creates a package.
- A user purchase a package and a transaction is created.
- A user can redeem an item and an order is created.

I'm struggling to find a simpler way to implement this workflow, with less redundancy.

This is my first time posting on Stackoverflow, please go easy on me :)

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, designing a Document-Based database highly depends on how the application presents the data to the user, in other words, what APIs are available. So, it depends on the requirements of the system and the user interface. Therefore, I made many assumptions during the suggested design.

I will start with the design, then explain why it might be sufficient for the assumed requirements of the system.

4 Collections are needed:

1. User.
2. Business.
3. Package.
4. Purchase.

**First: User collection.**
Used to store users' information ONLY, doesn't include a wallet.

**Second: Business collection**
Used to store businesses information ONLY, doesn't include packages.

**Third: Package collection**
Used to store packages, with denormalized business information for better querying.

```
const packageSchema = new Schema({
     itemInfo: {}, //The item to be sold in the package: (Name, description, ... etc). Try not to include more than one piece of information in a single field, for example: instead of name being: "ITEM_NAME (The big one)", separate them into two fields: name in one and the size in another. 
     businessInfo: {
        //All data of business needed to show the package in the UI, along with the businessId. 
     },
     count: {}, //Number of items 
     //.... Any other data  needed  for the  package, like price, description, ... etc. 
});
```

**Fourth: Purchase collection**
The purchase collection is a  representation of a user owning a package.

```
const purchaseSchema = new Schema({
     user: {}, //Id of the user 
     package: {}, //PackageId along with any denormalized data needed about the package to  display it to the user. 
     status: {type: String, required: true, enum: ["pending", "redeemed", "cancelled"], default: "pending"}, //Status of  the package, for the enum, use a constant variable accessible everywhere in the system, so it's easy to make it consistent.      
});
```

---

**Rationale for the design**
This is a list containing assumed functions in the system, along with assumed frequency of using each function, the number of calls to the DB, and the simplicity of the call.

- Admins.

  - Add new business:

    - Frequency: Low.
    - Number of calls to DB: 1.
    - Simplicity: Simple Insert call to the Business collection.
  - Modify an existing business:

    - Frequency: Very low.
    - Number of calls to DB: 3
    - Simplicity: Complex, and inefficient, requires updating: Business, Package, and Purchase collections.
- Businesses.

  - Add new Package:

    - Frequency: Medium.
    - Number of calls to DB: 1.
    - Simplicity: Very simple, one atomic insert call to the Package collection. (Denormalized business data can be sent along with the call, since the caller is the business itself.
  - Modify existing package:

    - Frequency: Low.
    - Number of calls to DB: 1 (Since already purchased items should not change).
    - Simplicity: Very simple, one atomic update call to the package collection.
- Customers.

  - Add (purchase) a package.

    - Frequency: Very high.
    - Number of calls  to DB: 1.
    - Simplicity: Very simple, one atomic insert call to Purchases collection.
  - Redeem a package.

    - Frequency: Very high.
    - Number of  calls to DB: 1.
    - Simplicity: Very simple, one atomic update call to the purchases collection (Change status, filter by status = "pending" and userId).
  - Get items in the wallet.

    - Frequency: Very high.
    - Number of calls to DB: 1.
    - Simplicity: Very simple, one atomic find call to purchases collection.
  - Show, with sorting and filtering, all available packages.

    - Frequency:  Very high.
    - Number of calls to DB: 1.
    - Simplicity: Very simple, one atomic find call to packages collection, all data are there.

Finally, the  design also makes it very easy to get statistics about data  as well, as  all of the following require only one simple (and efficient) call to the database:

1. Count number of businesses.
2. Count number of packages (Active, inactive, ... etc).
3. Sum total amount of money redeemed.
4. Sum total amount of money per business.
5. Average amount of money paid per user.
6. Total amount of money paid for a user.

And many more.